# how to include source javascript file in eval function of script engine

Tags: javascript

How to include external js as source in javascript i.e `<script type="text/javascript" src="/cordys/wcp/application.js" ></script>`.
But when i try like below as per pervious discussion i am getting "document is not defined" problem. Please help me how can i over come from this problem.

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

// Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;

// Then bind the event to the callback function.
// There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
script.onreadystatechange = callback;
script.onload = callback;

// Fire the loading
head.appendChild(script);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may have javascript disabled. Since *document* is the DOM variable referring to your entire HTML document, if you receive an error like the one you've written then something preventing the basis of javascript engine to start is happening.
Surely more informations (where are you using it, what do you wanna achieve, browser, version of the browser...) could help us understand your questions.